# CountIF with multipe variables

Tags: excel

Im trying to write a formula in excel to count the number of rows with "Yes" in column J only if column I has the entries "BJJ" or "KB".

This is what I have tried so far, but it doesnt work:

Countif(or(I1:I100,"BJJ",I1:I100,"KB")),J1:j100="yes"

Answer (score 2):

`=SUM(COUNTIFS(J1:J100,"yes",I1:I100,{"BJJ","KB"}))`

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You need `COUNTIFS`
This will do it - `=COUNTIFS(J:J,"Yes",I:I,"BJJ")+COUNTIFS(J:J,"Yes",I:I,"KB")`

Comment: @XOR LX's answer is actually better

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(I:I="BJJ")+--(I:I="KB"),--(J:J="Yes"))
```